# I am using the pyttsx3 API. I am creating filenames in for loop and adding mp3 extension. While files are saving, they are without the mp3 extension

Tags: python, for-loop, file-extension, pyttsx3

Essentially, I am iterating through a list and want to save an mp3 file for each element in the list. The file for each element would basically be reading out the list element. The name it would be saved under is the text it reads + the mp3 extension.

The textSpeech comes from the pyttsx3 module. I installed this in Pycharm by going to the terminal and typing pip install pyttsx3.

Here is my code, with just the for loop part shown.

```
import pyttsx3
textSpeech = pyttsx3.init()    
for x in dialogueColumns:
    words = df[x].values.tolist()
    for j in range(6, len(words)):
        name = "Step " + str(first[j]) + ": " + words[5] + ".mp3"
        textSpeech.save_to_file(words[j], name)
        textSpeech.runAndWait()
```

I have an example here that essentially replicates what I need:

```
 import pyttsx3
 textSpeech = pyttsx3.init()    
 names = ["this", "is", "a", "list", "of", "file", "names"]
 for index in range(0, len(names)):
     fileName = names[index] + ".mp3"
     # In the below line, the first input is the text to be spoken
     # the second input is the file name with the mp3 extension
     textSpeech.save_to_file(names[index], fileName)
     textSpeech.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Where is `textSpeech` coming from? What library or package are you using?

Comment: @Grismar I imported it from pyttsx3

Comment: @eyllanesc I just added it in

Comment: @Anonymous Please provide a [mre], Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: @eyllanesc Hello, I just did that

Comment: @Anonymous If you are on windows then the directory manager is probably hiding the extensions, have you verified that other files show the extensions(images, videos, etc)?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I have opened them from file explorer and played them. They are all mp3

Comment: I think you did not understand me, the windows explorer can be configured to show or hide the extensions (in your case .mp3) and by default it is configured to be hidden so I suspect that this is your case and therefore you code has no problems but you have to configure the windows explorer to make the extensions visible.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ah, I see. I just changed that. However, even before the change, the other files (like in the example in my post) were showing the mp3 extensions and were playable. I ran the code again, and the extension is still not appearing, neither in Pycharm nor in my File Explorer.

Comment: Not only is there a space in your filename (which should be fine), but there's a colon there as well, and that's not allowed. `name = "Step " + str(first[j]) + ": " + words[5] + ".mp3"`

Comment: @Grismar Thank you very much, removing the colon fixed it!

Comment: I added it to the answer - feel free to accept it, or remove your question, so that it no longer shows as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in the code, it is in the configuration of your Windows explorer.

Open the Windows File Explorer, select `View`, `Options`, select the `View` tab,  find the option `Hide extensions for known file types` and make sure it is not checked. Uncheck it otherwise and select `OK`.

Rerun your script and you'll likely find that the files you're writing do indeed have the mp3 extension.

The problem with your code is straightforward: not only is there a space in your filename (which should be fine in most cases), but there's a colon there as well, and that's not allowed.

```
name = "Step " + str(first[j]) + ": " + words[5] + ".mp3"
```

Comment: Hello, that was unchecked. The other files I tested this out with did indeed have the mp3 extension. Thank you anyway.